# Unity: Camera is jumpy/jerky when using touch grab to move rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, touch

Using Unity, I'm trying to move my turrets rotation using first person camera by using touch, I grab from side of screen to center from the direction i want to go to like in google maps, the touch grab will move my camera there smoothly.

Problem is the camera being very jerky, not smooth in position.

In Global

```
private float smoothTouchFactor = 5;
```

This is the code I am using in `Update()`

```
Quaternion rotation;

if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        x += touch.deltaPosition.x * xSpeed * 0.02f;
        y -= touch.deltaPosition.y * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0f);
        turretHeadToMove.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(turretHeadToMove.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * smoothTouchFactor);
    }
}

rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0f);
turretHeadToMove.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(turretHeadToMove.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * smoothTouchFactor);
```

If I dont add the last 2 lines after the if(touchCount) then the camera goes back to initial position after i lift my finger off the screen.

---

Here is the mouse axis Mouse X/Y code that works and moves the turret with no jerky motion, smoothly.

```
private float xSpeed = 40.0f;
private float ySpeed = 40.0f;

in Update()
x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02f;
y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0f);
turretHeadToMove.rotation = rotation;
```

Comment: Is `turretHeadToMove` a `Transform`?

Comment: @Ruzihm yes a Transform

Comment: in `Update` does it always run this line `turretHeadToMove.rotation = rotation;` even when you are using touch controls, or do you have that turned off? If you turn it off, can you add the code that does that please?

Comment: @Ruzihm yes if on PC I run the mouse code only if on Touch device then I turn off the mouse code and use this new code. Also worth noting the Transform called `turretHead` is a child within a turret model, within another parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description of needing those "two lines" at the end, it sounds like you have code elsewhere that's constantly trying to reset their rotation.  So, we add a variable to keep `rotation` consistent with the `Quaternion` set the last time the touch control was done, and just be sure to assign it to `turretHeadToMove.rotation` before handling the touch controls.

Then, you can use `Euler` to create a `Quaternion` of how much you want to rotate this frame. And then multiply the current rotation by that amount in order to get the new rotation

Altogether this might look like:

As a field:

```
private Quaternion savedRotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

In `Update`:

```
// Add it before the block so that modifications to `localRotation` are consistent with memory
turretHeadToMove.rotation = savedRotation;

if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Quaternion previousRotation = turretHeadToMove.rotation;

        Quaternion rotationThisFrame = Quaternion.Euler(
                 touch.deltaPosition.y * ySpeed, 
                 touch.deltaPosition.x * xSpeed, 0f);

        turretHeadToMove.rotation = previousRotation * rotationThisFrame;

        savedRotation = turretHeadToMove.rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and its not moving at all, I have the `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` at 200 and still nothing, It moved millimeters if I swipe hard enough. Also the `smoothTouchFactor` to 50 and nothing too. What can It be?

Comment: It keeps going back to initial position

Comment: @WokerHead xSpeed and ySpeed might have to be set really high because you're multiplying it by 0.02f. it might be better to get rid of that part instead. I removed that multiplication from my answer. I also edited my answer to include a version with the equivalent of your "two lines" at the end. You'll have to add a `private Quaternion savedRotation` field to your class to make it work.

Comment: I don't understand why its still not working, still hardly moving at all no matter the values I put for `xSpeed` or `smoothTouchFactor`. But I also added the mouse code that works for PC and not touch. It seamlessly works perfect it never goes back to initial position. Anything different between both code aside from mouse and touch difference? I know I have to drag mouse to move turret, in touch its not just moving touch but swiping to move rotation. Also thanks for constantly trying!

Comment: Does it move if you comment out `Quaternion.RotateTowards...` and just do `turretHeadToMove.localRotation = targetRotation;`?

Comment: Yes it does, I made the `xSpeed` down to 5f. But it moves crazy fast and not smooth. If I hold the touch and move around then its too crazy to know where its going.

Comment: `smoothTouchFactor` is the maximum rotational speed in degrees per second. Try putting `RotateTowards` back in and set `smoothTouchFactor` to `180` and see how that goes

Comment: I added it and it moves but not accurate. I swipe to move and it jumps to somewhat in that direction, at least its not going to initial position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193708/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-wokerhead).

Comment: I uploaded the gif

Comment: @WokerHead I updated my answer. Found a typo & got rid of RotateTowards per your feedback. Also, I've been informed that the warning about editing `rotation` is about its components because it's a quaternion, not because replacing `rotation` can have unexpected results or anything.